# Next without For Error - What is wrong with this code?

Tags: vba, excel

I assume there is something wrong with my code below, because it is giving me the following error: `Compile error: Next without For`

What is wrong with my code? Thanks! :)

```
Sub CreateCharts()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 5

        col = Columns(i).Select

        Dim xaxis As Range
        Dim yaxis As Range
        Set yaxis = Range("$" & col & "$152", "$" & col & "$156")
        Set xaxis = Range("$A$152", "$A$156")
        Dim c As Chart
        Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
        Set c = c.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1")
        c.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

        Dim s As Series
        Set s = c.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With s
            .Values = yaxis
            .XValues = xaxis

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an `End With`:

```
    With s
        .Values = yaxis
        .XValues = xaxis
    End With ' <====== HERE
Next i
```